# What is the limit to the number of unique items in Spark's ALS?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using Spark's ALS recommender implementation for a project at work, and there is a lot of discussion going on around how it will handle scale. But not for the number of events, for the number of *items* in the product catalogue.

My concern is that Spark `RowMatrix` objects have a hard limit on the number of columns they can handle in factorization tasks ([~65,500](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg/distributed.py#L348)). Obviously, ALS takes a sparse matrix in the form of an `RDD`:

```
sc.parallelize([(usr, itm, rtg), (usr2, itm2, rtg)])
```

However, I can't find any discussion anywhere as to whether it's constructing a dense matrix on the backend where I might run into column limitations as a result of > 65k items. Is there any discussion or documentation on the practical limitations of Spark's ALS implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially `RowMatrix.computePrincipalComponents` is completely irrelevant to the process. `ml.ALS` doesn't use `mllib.linalg` data structures. `ml.ALS` uses its own blockwise algorithm.

Theoretical limit is the range of identifiers (`Int` or `Long` depending on the specialization), but I doubt it was ever tested for a dataset like this.

Comment: I appreciate the follow up. The `computePrincipalComponents` function was the link because it mentioned the column limitation. I understand it's not used in the factorization process, but just wanted to point to some documentation that referenced the 65k col limit. I did not know about the block-wise algorithm, though. That sets my mind at ease to an extent... but I suppose load testing is the only answer here?